# Regex/Java Pattern : Finding occurrences of a sub string in a string with fault tolerance of 1 or more characters

Tags: java, regex, string, match

**How to find occurrences of a sub string in a string with fault tolerance of 1 or more characters?**

Example.

Source : John Smith

With Fault tolerance 1 Character:

- Sub String 1: Jahn should result to 1
- Sub String 2: Jonn should result to 1
- Sub String 3: Johm should result to 1
- Sub String 4:
  johm should result to 1  //ignore case

With Fault tolerance 2 Character:

- Sub String 1: Jann should result to 1
- Sub String 2: Joom should result to 1 
  and etc...

Any Regex Solution ??
Java Pattern Matching? In this case, a method like this

```
int countOccurrenceWithFaultTolerance(String source, String subString, int faultTolerance) {
    // TODO
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

May be I found this,

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    final int mismatchTolerance = 1;
    final String text = "bubbles";
    final String pattern = "bu";

    final int textIndexMax = text.length() - pattern.length() + 1;
    for (int textIndex = 0; textIndex < textIndexMax; textIndex++) {
        int missed = 0;

        for (int patternIndex = 0; patternIndex < pattern.length(); patternIndex++) {
            final char textChar = text.charAt(textIndex + patternIndex);
            final char patternChar = pattern.charAt(patternIndex);
            if (textChar != patternChar) {
                missed++;
            }
            if (missed > mismatchTolerance) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (missed <= mismatchTolerance) {
            final String match = text.substring(textIndex, textIndex + pattern.length());
            System.out.println("Index: " + textIndex + " Match: " + match);
        }
    }
 }
```

}